# I'm having trouble with a small algorithm

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have a number of objects represented as balls in a gravity simulation, they're clumped together in 3 groups (for example, but it could be any number), how can give each object value depending on which group (1,2,3) it's in?

I only got this far, I can't figure it out...

```
var objects = [/* the balls */];

...

this.objects.forEach(
    function(one) {
        this.objects.forEach(
            function(two) {
                if(distance(one, two) <= 0) {
                    // these two are in the same group
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

The thing is, two balls in the same group might not necessarily be touching because there may a another ball in between them, but all balls in a group touch at least one other ball in the group.

The value would just be something like "this.group = 1;".

Any ideas are much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot disambiguate balls from which group it came from.

Try using three arrays to represent the three groups, or a more object-like structure that can reference which group the balls come from.

Comment: The balls don't necessarily come from a group, they're free to move and change groups, or groups can merge and split. Think of it as a simple 2d gravity simulation in space. So I need to differentiate them from scratch each time.